# How do i add a keybind to an already existing event?

Tags: java

I am making a claculator app. I have it set up so that i can click the buttons and add a number to the display. I want it so that when i click the same number button on the keyboard it does the same thing. below is the relevant lines of code .

```
b1.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() 
    {
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) 
        {
            b1MouseClicked(evt);
        }
    });

private void b1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) 
{                                
    isDigit = Character.isDigit(operand);

    numberDisplayText = numbersDisplay.getText();

    if(isDigit == true)
    {
        if(numberDisplayText.length() <= 7)
        {
            numberDisplayTextAdd = "1";
            numbersDisplay.setText(numberDisplayText + numberDisplayTextAdd);
        }

        else
        {
            errorsDisplay.setText("error: too many digits. Use an operand.");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //Don't add the number if the operand has been used.
    }
}
```

Below is a github link to the full class.

https://github.com/Phidipedes/CalculatorApp

Answer (score 1):

this is not a problem, it's a simple question that you can find out very easily if you are looking for a bit in Google. But you are already new as I will solve the doubt as best as I can.

You must implement the KeyListerner interface just like the mouse listener. Each key has a code so that the program recognizes the key you have pressed.
So your code would be:

```
    public void keyPressed (KeyEvent e) {
       if (e.VK_1 == e.getKeyCode ()){
         numberDisplayTextAdd = "1";
         numbersDisplay.setText (numberDisplayText + numberDisplayTextAdd);
       }
    }
```

I hope you have been helpful. but next vaez tries to find something else before asking.

A greeting

Comment: I get an error "void is an invalid type for the variable keyPressed"